# Advancing from Arduino programming to other platforms

Tags: arduino

I am quite new to electrical engineering, but I have a couple of complicated project on Arduino which I made and soldered completely by myself. I am creating "stuff" to actually gift it people around me (i.e. box with secret cache under it, which opens with RFID-card).

Though Arduino controllers are quite cumbersome, expensive and very easy to use. I am looking for cheaper platform that might be not that easy to use, but which will satisfy my needs.

Can anyone please give me couple of advices which direction should I move to reach my goals, and which platform I could use for my needs.

Comment: Create your own pcbs

Comment: Please describe your needs in more detail. For example, what sort of I/O do you need, is it all RFID or are their other requirements? This site discourages questions and answers that are vague or based on opinion. Such questions are likely to get closed. Please read the [help] to learn how to ask good questions.

Comment: @gbulmer While, yes, this question can be construe as broad, I don't think it's too close to being closable, as the question "so I've been doing Arduino, now what?" comes up regularly and usually much less clearly worded.

Comment: Chinese Arduino clones are quite cheap, and nanon and pro mini clones even cheaper. Als: consider Cortex chips, LPC1114 DIP28 is nice and easy to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Sticking to the brand:

There will be many smaller little board people have made around small-ish microcontrollers from the same manufacturer, [being Atmel](http://www.atmel.com/).

Many designs exist using the following devices (links are examples of projects - even the old ones are good inspiration): [ATTiny13](https://hackaday.com/2015/01/02/holiday-cheer-from-the-attiny13/), [ATTiny25/45/85](http://hackaday.com/2011/05/20/using-an-avr-as-an-rfid-tag/), ATTiny261/461/861, [ATTiny2323](http://www.serasidis.gr/circuits/smscontrol/smscontroller.htm), [ATMega8](https://nirzaree.wordpress.com/2012/03/07/make-a-standalone-atmega8-circuit/), [ATMega16](http://www.elec.uow.edu.au/avr/guides/Getting-started-C-programming-Atmel-Studio-6.pdf), ATMega164/324.

-- Especially the ATMega16 link is interesting if you intend on trying Atmel Studio.

Newer processors of those families also exist, and you would be able to learn all about them at [the Atmel site](http://www.atmel.com/), using for example [the ATTiny parametric](http://www.atmel.com/v2PFResults.aspx#(actives:!(8238,8394,8362,8282,8431,8300,8358,8392,8378,8445,8236,8449,8474,8248,8264,8447,8256,8254,8286,8462,8429,8458,8466,8400,8302,8278),data:(area:%27%27,category:%2734864%5B33180%5B33086%5D%5D%27,pm:!((i:8238,v:!(1,7)),(i:8394,v:!(0,7)),(i:8362,v:!(5,12)),(i:8282,v:!(6)),(i:8431,v:!(1,9)),(i:8300,v:!(1,5)),(i:8358,v:!(2,20)),(i:8392,v:!(0,1)),(i:8378,v:!n),(i:8445,v:!(5,6,9)),(i:8236,v:!(0,9)),(i:8449,v:!(1,3)),(i:8474,v:!(0)),(i:8248,v:!(0,1)),(i:8264,v:!(1,2)),(i:8447,v:!(0,1)),(i:8256,v:!(1,4)),(i:8254,v:!(4,18)),(i:8286,v:!(0)),(i:8462,v:!(0,2)),(i:8429,v:!(0,2)),(i:8458,v:!(0,1)),(i:8466,v:!(5)),(i:8400,v:!(0,7)),(i:8302,v:!(0)),(i:8278,v:!(0))),view:table),sc:1)) search or [the ATMega parametric](http://www.atmel.com/v2PFResults.aspx#(actives:!(8238,8394,8362,8282,8431,8300,8358,8392,8378,8445,8236,8449,8474,8248,8264,8447,8256,8254,8286,8462,8429,8458,8466,8400,8302,8278),data:(area:%27%27,category:%2734864%5B33180%5B33085%5D%5D%27,pm:!((i:8238,v:!(4,14)),(i:8394,v:!(4,15)),(i:8362,v:!(11,12)),(i:8282,v:!(6)),(i:8431,v:!(6,23)),(i:8300,v:!(4,8)),(i:8358,v:!(12,56)),(i:8392,v:!(0,1)),(i:8378,v:!n),(i:8445,v:!(5,6,9)),(i:8236,v:!(7,20)),(i:8449,v:!(1,6)),(i:8474,v:!(0)),(i:8248,v:!(0,1)),(i:8264,v:!(1,4)),(i:8447,v:!(0,1)),(i:8256,v:!(1)),(i:8254,v:!(8,14)),(i:8286,v:!(0,1)),(i:8462,v:!(0,4)),(i:8429,v:!(1,5)),(i:8458,v:!(0,2)),(i:8466,v:!(1,2,5)),(i:8400,v:!(2,12)),(i:8302,v:!(0)),(i:8278,v:!(0,1))),view:table),sc:1)) search.

#### EDIT: Turns out many Arduino's can also program almost all Tiny/Mega's - Though how I didn't investigate.

If you have an AVRISP (about €35 if it's genuine Atmel Brand) and their own, free Atmel Studio you have all the tools you need to program any ATTiny/ATMega and can even start making your own designs. All of the most common ones these days have an internal RC oscillator, so you'd not need to worry about crystals and all that right away. Unless you need a very accurate clock.

The most difficult step then is getting the hang of doing more programming and interrupt stuff yourself, to allow you to broaden the applications by not being dependent on libraries that limit the possibilities (and in many cases also bloat your code, which is annoying in a 1kByte controller).

#### Not Sticking to the Brand:

Another very famous manufacturer of small controllers is Microchip with their PIC series. Many people use them to make their own projects, much like the Atmels. The advantage of that is that when you search for a PIC12F or PIC16F or whatever their series are now (I've been out of PIC for 10 years now) won't constantly lead you back to an Arduino that has them. :-)

The most affordable PICs will also probably be [the 8bit devices](http://www.microchip.com/design-centers/8-bit), but many people seem to be using [more of the 32bit](http://www.microchip.com/design-centers/32-bit) when using PICs than they do with Atmels, so maybe there's something there price-wise or in usability.

Microchip is also very good in the DSP regions, making special DSPIC series, here they definitely beat out Atmel, where I feel Atmel is easier to use when it comes to peripheral functionality (internal hardware blocks that do stuff like serial or ADC, etc).

---

There's also the Texas Instruments [MSP400-series](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/microcontrollers_16-bit_32-bit/overview.page) with very affordable LaunchPad series boards to try and play that are sometimes as little as €10, but designed by professionals.

But I know hardly anything about TI that's not ARM-based.

(The BeagleBone series is also made by TI themselves, the more professionally designed alternative to the Raspberry, if you will. It's a bad comparison, but to put it in usable terms)

Comment: The main advantage of AVRs from a hobbyist perspective has nothing to do with the chips themselves. AVR-GCC is a fully featured free and open source C and C++ compiler for 8-bit AVRs, while the PICs only have proprietary compilers (with the exception of the uncompleted SDCC target) with the usual restrictive licences.

Comment: @jms I fully agree. Both in my personal life and in business I use many different applications, including KEIL/ARM's own uVision, and Atmel Studio including all the tools it offers is still the most worthwhile, due in no small part to AVR-GCC as well as their choice to buy the rights to use the MSVisual Shell for code view and editing. uVision does have some great stuff, don't get me wrong, but the code editing and view options in it are horrendous.